# php server-side automatic caching

Tags: php, apache, caching

I need to configure my apache so it run particular php file every, say, 1 hour.
That php file should download something from other website and put downloaded data in database (create cache). How can i do this? On my server, i got "cPanel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Cron Job, that should do the trick

Comment: you can set it up in cPanel, its very user friendly

Answer (score 0):

You should configure [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on the server, using the crontab file, as apache isn't designed to run processes at a determined time

Answer (score 0):

An example of a cronjob I use to export once a day some data coming from the database to text files:
25 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/site/exports.php >> /var/www/site/application/exports/logs/logs.txt

Then after a few minutes I upload those exports through a little bash script through sftp:
35 0 * * * /bin/sh /usr/local/cron/transfert.sh